# The boundary point of every open set of a metric space is a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider a metric space $X$ and its open subset $A$. $\newcommand{\ball}[2]{B_{#1}(#2)} \newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}$

Proposition: $\forall x \in X: x \in \partial A \Rightarrow x \in L(A)$ where $L(A)$ is the set of limit points of $A$

My proof: Let $x$ be a boundary point of $A$. Then, $x \in \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$, i.e., $x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \not\in A^\circ = A$ because $A$ is open. For all $\eps > 0$, there is $y \in A$ such that $y \in \ball{\eps}{x}$. From the fact that $x \not\in A$, we have that for all $\eps >0$, there is $y \in A$ such that $y \in \ball{\eps}{x}$ different from $x$.

Please check if my proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, since your last line is exactly the definition of limit point.

Just as a curiosity, note that every limit point in a metric space (*first countable* would be enough) can be reached by a convergent sequence. This property seems trivial, but may fail in general topological spaces where the topology is not induced by a metric. Then, more sophisticated tools like *nets* or *ultrafilters* are required to characterize the closure of a set.

Comment: Your answer improved my knowledge about first countable spaces. Thanks.